# execvp(array[i], array) where array[NUMBER][NUMBER] error

Tags: c, arrays, execvp

I'm trying to send an array of a predefined size of user input to the execvp function, however I receive a warning from the compiler. 
There is ratio of text-code that stackoverflow requires so I'm just trying to fill it up so that I can submit my post. Don't bother reading this, just head down to the code below. Thank you in advance!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INPUTSIZE 50
#define INPUTCOUNT 10

int parseInput(char string[*][INPUTSIZE]);

void main(int argc, char **argv){
    char prompt = '#', shellInput[INPUTCOUNT][INPUTSIZE];
    pthread_t thread;
    pid_t processID;
    int rc;

    while(1){
        printf("%c", prompt);

        if(parseInput(shellInput)==EOF){
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        processID = fork();
        if(processID == 0){
            execvp(shellInput[0], shellInput);
            printf("Uknown command\n");
        }


        printf("Nope.gif!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

    }
}

int parseInput(char string[INPUTCOUNT][INPUTSIZE]){
    char *inputString, *tempString;
    int i, status; 
    size_t bytecount = INPUTSIZE+1;

    inputString = (char *)malloc(INPUTCOUNT*INPUTSIZE);
    tempString = (char *)malloc(INPUTSIZE);
    status = getline(&inputString, &bytecount, stdin);

    tempString = strtok(inputString, " ");


    for(i = 0; i < INPUTCOUNT && tempString != NULL; i++){
        strncpy(string[i], tempString, INPUTSIZE);
        tempString = strtok(NULL, " \n\r");
    }
    strncpy(string[i], "NULL", sizeof(NULL));

    return status;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(string[i], "NULL", sizeof(NULL));` "NULL" != NULL

Comment: 1) this line: 'int parseInput(char string[*][INPUTSIZE]); would be much better/clearer written as: 'int parseInput(char **string);'  2) tgurn on all the compiler warnings then the compiler would have told you that this line: 'void main(int argc, char **argv){'  is not valid, it should be: 'int main(int argc, char **argv){'.  main() ALWAYS returns int.

Comment: neither argc nor argv[] were used, so the compiler will raise warnings about the two unused parameters.   Warnings are where the compiler sees some doubtful code.  To fix that warning use: 'int main(void)'

Comment: the code block beginning with: 'if(processID == 0){' is all in a child process.  the process, if not exited, will continue around the loop, doing the same thing as the parent.  to avoid that problem, insert a 'exit()' statement just before the closing brace of that code block

Comment: all calls to malloc (and family) 1) in C, do not cast the returned value  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: tempstring contains a pointer to a malloc'd memory area.   Then tempstring is overlayed by the first call to strtok().  This results in a memory leak as the original pointer to the malloc'd memory is lost.

Comment: regarding this pair of lines: 'status = getline(&inputString, &bytecount, stdin);
    tempString = strtok(inputString, " ");' if the input string only contains a single item, like the name of a program to execute,  Then strtok will find the trailing NUL byte .  However, that byte will be past the newline character.  so the execvp will be trying to exec a program those name ends with a newline.  It will not find that program.   similar considerations exist for the last parameter when there are parameters.  Suggest: replacing any newline with a '\0' before parsing

Comment: regarding this line: 'strncpy(string[i], "NULL", sizeof(NULL));' will not work. suggest: 'striing[i] = NULL;' however, if all the available array locations in string[INPUTCOUNT] were already used, then 'i' would be an index beyond the bounds of the array. This is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: execvp only returns when there is an error.  suggest notifying the user of the error, perhaps by inserting a 'perror()' statement

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
char shellInput[INPUTCOUNT][INPUTSIZE];
```

The type of variable `shellInput` is "array of `INPUTCOUNT` arrays of `INPUTSIZE` `char`s".  In most contexts, `shellInput` is automatically converted to type "pointer to array of `INPUTSIZE` `char`s" (`char (*)[INPUTSIZE]`).  That's not at all the same thing as "array of pointer to `char`" (`(char *)[]`), which is the required type of the second argument to `execvp()`.

(Technically, `execvp()` is actually declared to accept a `const` array (of non-`const` pointers), but it is acceptable to pass a non-const one.)

It looks like you want something more like this:

```
    char *shellInput[INPUTCOUNT + 1];

    /* ... */

int parseInput(char *string[]) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_len;
    ssize_t n_read = getline(&line, &line_len, stdin);
    char *token;
    int input_count = 0;

    if (n_read < 0) {
        return n_read;
    }

    for (token = strtok(line, " "); token && (input_count < INPUTCOUNT);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        string[input_count++] = strdup(token);
    }
    string[input_count] = NULL;
    free(line);

    return n_read;
}
```

Note, too, that the parent process needs to free the elements of `shellInput` (up to, but not including the first `NULL`) after each `fork()`.  Additionally, note that there's no particular reason why you couldn't make `shellInput` have type `char **`, and teach `parseInput()` to arrange to dynamically allocate enough space for any number of command-line words.

Answer (score 0):

You array should be an array of pointers to char, not array of array of char. This is because the logical end of the array of strings (aka char *) that you must give to exec must end with a nul pointer. If you want to exec to `ls -l myfile` the array must be equals to:

```
char *args[] = { "ls", "-l", "myfile", NULL };
```